# How could I find the Plan command?

Tags: osx, users, finger

I tried finger and find a Plan

```
$ finger $USER
Login: me                   Name: me
Directory: /Users/me                Shell: /usr/local/bin/bash
On since Tue Nov 13 07:33 (CST) on console, idle 1 day 9:44 (messages off)
On since Tue Nov 13 07:33 (CST) on ttys001
No Mail.
No Plan.
```

at the ending, there are `No Mail` and `No Plan`

I know that Mail in `/var/mail` and there's a command `$ which mail
/usr/bin/mail`

How about Plan, where could I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "plan" is the `.plan` text file in the user's home directory.  Its contents would be displayed in the `finger` output if available.  If available, `finger` would also display the contents of the file `~/.project` under a "Project:" header.

See the `finger` manual on your system (`man finger`).  On macOS, this command may also use the files `~/.forward` and `~/.pubkey`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Plan command.

You need to create a text file `~/.plan`. This will then be shown when someone does a `finger yourusername`. This file can be arbitrarily long.

See `man finger` for more information.

Comment: It's `.pubkey` on macOS rather than `.pgpkey`. Where is this manual except from?

Comment: From CentOS 7.  I'll delete that part, I didn't notice the tag `osx`.